# Regression of a discrete variable on two others, one discrete the other categorical

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, model, variable

I have a study which pairs up two people and has them go through a sequence of processes.  They are then measured according to three variables: similarity, competitive status, and trust.  Similarity is a discrete random variable with values from 0 to 25.  Competitive status is a three-level ordinal categorical variable, taking values "win", "lose", or "tie".  Trust is discrete numeric taking values from 0 to 100.  I would like to see how similarity and competitive status affect trust, including interaction effects.

I'm wondering what the best approach is--should I treat the discrete variables like continuous ones, since the range of their values is so large that the distinction becomes unimportant?

Is it valid to classify each pair of participants by "win", "lose", or "tie" and then run a regression, since an ordered pair with level "win" is the same as the reverse ordering labeled with "lose"?

Is there a valid regression model that I can run in R for this?

Finally, would anything change if I added extra variables like age and gender?